# Map key with value as standard

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a non-empty string containing only printable ASCII (codepoints 0x20 to 0x7E), **write the shortest program** or function that map the key to its value. Inside the string the key will always have a value and vice-versa.

How the `key` is made:

- Start with an opening parenthesis `(`
- Contains letters and/or numbers `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- It ends with a closing parenthesis `)`

What `value` does it refer to:

- All characters until the next opening parenthesis or end of string
- Contains letters and/or numbers `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

#### Context

This test is based on a real case study, i.e. the reading of the application identifiers following the GS1 standards. If you want more information you can look through the documentation at https://ref.gs1.org/ai/

#### Test Cases

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `(01)99012345670019(10)Ab1234` | `01 -> 99012345670019` `10 -> Ab1234` |
| `(3102)00122515190521` | `3102 -> 00122515190521` |
| `(337n)001234` | `337n -> 001234` |

Comment: I take it we don’t have to handle the case where the keys and/or values contain parentheses themselves?

Comment: @macOSisthebestOS Actually, in my explanation that case is not very clear. Technically I wrote that the `value` ​​can contain any character, therefore also parentheses. To clarify, since I didn't include your observation in the examples I modified the question by excluding special characters within the `value`. Being relatively new to the community I hope this action can follow the community  guidelines.

Comment: By the way, since I'm a Java enthusiast, I hope to see an answer written in my favorite language!

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you mean by map the key to its value. For instance, I want to use a language whose only data type is string and doesn't have functions, only full programs, so should my program output a full program which performs the desired mapping?

Comment: @Nail By "map" I mean connecting two elements as if they were key-value. You can write an output string that represents a json, an array, or whatever you prefer. The constant is that there is an association between the key and its value.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input will contain only keys and values? Several existing answers fail if additional junk (i.e. printable characters not in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`) is allowed to appear before/between/after the key-value pairs, e.g. `***(key1)value1***(key2)value2***`. (I note that you state that 'the key will always have a value and vice-versa', but as I read it, this doesn't exclude additional junk.)

Comment: Could @Neil's hypothetical language perform the mapping as a curried function, taking two parameters the string and a key and outputting the value?

Comment: "You can write an output string that represents a json, an array, or whatever you prefer." My problem with this vague challenge is that I don't see how "whatever you prefer" excludes the format the input is already in. If `[[01, 99012345670019], [10, Ab1234]]` and `{"01": "99012345670019", "10": "Ab1234"}` and `01 -> 99012345670019 10 -> Ab1234` are all valid output formats, then why not `(01)99012345670019(10)Ab1234`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this per Lynn's comment.  I agree that there needs be a more strict description of the output format (I'm happy to give suggestions too).  The clarifications already given also need to go in the body challenge somehow. I will happily reopen this when those are clarified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), <s>64</s> 46 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), <s>8</s> 5.75 bytes

```
\(/Ḣ\)/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFwoL+G4olxcKS8iLCIiLCIoMDEpOTkwMTIzNDU2NzAwMTkoMTApQWIxMjM0Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
0110100010010100000101101101001111001010010100
```

Returns a list of lists. -2.25 bytes thanks to @pacman256

### Explained

```
\(/Ḣ\)/­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
\(/      # ‎⁡Split the input on (s
   Ḣ     # ‎⁢Remove the first item
    \)/  # ‎⁣Split each item in that on )s
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [5.75](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFwoL+G4olxcKS8iLCIiLCIoMDEpOTkwMTIzNDU2NzAwMTkoMTApQWIxMjM0Il0=)

Comment: Oh, a *very* aesthetically pleasing solution!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda x:dict(i.split(')')for i in x[1:].split('('))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcoxDoMwDIXhnVNkw16QnZCiIDH0HG0HKKBaoiGCDPT0NKnUN/7fC5/4Wr05Z9Wp@7n072Hs1dGO8owg1R4WiVBiifO6KVHi1XHj9vGHRHhmWsRPWdcweSBsC5UWNvERZshY7XGTAJj@QIzOEWtT20tDxA6Y8DrkUIBh0pii1pYtO7KaUzSN/0VTfwE)

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42 31</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
->s{Hash[*s.scan(/\w+/)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf16642iOxOCNaq1ivODkxT0M/plxbXzO29n@BQlq0koaBoaalpYGhkbGJqZm5gYGhpYahgaZjElBAKZYLosTY0MBIEyhlZGRqaGpoaWBqZIiQMzbPA8sZmyjF/gcA)

Thanks @Dingus for -11 bytes and forcing me to do more research on hashes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 20 bytes

```perl
s/\(/
/g;s/\)/ -> /g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP0ZDn0s/3RrI0NRX0LVT0E///1/DwFDT0tLA0MjYxNTM3MDA0FLD0EDTMQkk8C@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BocF/3QIA)

Comment: Nice! You can save another 3 bytes using `y;(;\n` too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP0ZTX0HXTkE/3brSWsOa6/9/DQNDTUtLA0MjYxNTM3MDA0NLDUMDTcckkMC//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¦'(¡')δ¡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0DJ1jUML1TXPbTm08P9/DQNDTUtLA0MjYxNTM3MDA0NLDUMDTcckkAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Q8vUNQ4tVNc8t@XQwv86/6OVNAwMNS0tDQyNjE1MzcwNDAwtNQwNNB2TQAJKOgpKGsaGBkaaQHEjI1NDU0NLA1MjQ4i4sXkeWByoLhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
¦         # Remove the first "("-character of the (implicit) input-string
 '(¡     '# Then split on all remaining "("
      δ   # Map over each substring:
    ') ¡ '#  Split on ")"
          # (after which the list of pairs is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656).*

```hs
g=span(>'*')
f""=[]
f(_:s)|(a,_:b)<-g s,(c,d)<-g b=(a,c):f d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3RCoIwGIXv9xQ/u3GLFdtsyaQFPUBPICIznUk6pHnZu68lXXWuDofv8D1sePbTFONgwmI9uWS7jCKHsalq5EhTBvomljVlS8/7AQIjd9ZttTVpv9PSQRfXPqwBDFSACRdUay5kflSngnOhieD02n4HjOAXlsBccEkTIKUSSmiupPgD8sJvQHpCjdBsR58ks11uQJbX6Fc4gKOw2eMH)

### Invalid (but cooler) solution, 55 bytes

```hs
f""=[]
f(_:s)|[(a,_:b)]<-lex s,[(c,d)]<-lex b=(a,c):f d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BDsIgFET3nOKHFSRo@CA2NHbhATwBaRpaS2xsm0a6cOHdERtdOLuZeZO5@XjvxzGlQGnlahJYU0b@csyLpmx5fdqN/ROicKwT159tq1x3vAxwTWsf1wgVOKBMIrdWotIHcyykRMtQ8nP7CSiBr0QGNUrFM6CUQYNWGoX/gNe6mDciT6EmZPLDnF8mv1yALY9hXmEPgcN2n94)

Relies heavily on the built-in `lex` function that lexes Haskell lexemes. That means it *almost* works for the challenge at hand but it fails because it lexes anything that starts with a digit and ends with a letter as two different tokens, i.e. `337n` as `337` and `n`.

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3RCsIgGEbvfYofb6ZhoS4bjgx6gJ5gjOHapNEmW@6ydzdb0N3HOQe@hw3PfhxjXEyYrSeXbJdR5DA2VY0cacpA38Sypmzpeb9AYOTOum22JvE7LR10ce3DGsAggAow4YJqzYXMj@pUcC40EZxe2y/AKWEpyQWXNCkplVBCcyXFX@WF39SvrhGa7ODBwGTnG5D5NfgVDuAobK/xAw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 56 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/.(.*?)\)([^(]*)/g,(_,a,b)=>s[a]=b,s={})&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fci7DoIwFADQv4F7SS2t7w7FuDA46OCIaFpSGwwBwiUEY/z2Gs94XmYyVA11Py6mfch1mHU288H1jakcpBx4csAbQnGHMsHUM3gwwyzqjApTastIf74YRRSqrqWucbzpPJyulzOncahbXz/fkEMMQqJSQi5X6812J4RUIAUe7T9iRAw/)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 23 bytes

Prompts for string.

```
((+\m∊'()')⊂m←⎕)~¨⊂'()'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv4aGdkzuo44udQ1Ndc1HXU25QCmgEs26QyuAPJDof6A6rv9pXOoaBoaalpYGhkbGJqZm5gYGhpYahgaajkkgAXUukAJjQwMjTaCEkZGpoamhpYGpkSFUwtg8DywBVAkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 7 bytes

```
'(÷')÷Ḣ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCInKMO3JynDt+G4oiIsIiIsIigwMSk5OTAxMjM0NTY3MDAxOSgxMClBYjEyMzQiLCIzLjQuMiJd)
port of vyxal 2

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
↯∞_2⊜□¬∊,"()"
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oav4oieXzLiipzilqHCrOKIiiwiKCkiCgpGICIoMDEpOTkwMTIzNDU2NzAwMTkoMTApQWIxMjM0IgpGICIoMzEwMikwMDEyMjUxNTE5MDUyMSIKRiAiKDMzN24pMDAxMjM0Igo=)

-1 thanks to RomanPro100

```
↯∞_2⊜□¬∊,"()"
       ∊,"()"   # mask of parentheses
      ¬         # invert
    ⊜□          # partition by box
↯∞_2            # reshape into pairs
```

Comment: It can be shorter if you replace `:"()".` with `,"()"`

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>174</s> 172 bytes

```java
import java.util.*; s->{HashMap<String,String>c=new HashMap<String,String>();for(String a:s.split("\\(")){String[]b=a.split("\\)");if(b.length>1)c.put(b[0],b[1]);}return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8/b8IwEMXn5FOcMtkSWDaBotYlY9WFiREYnJAEU@NY8YUKoXz21BKhldpO9@f39N7dSV3UtHGlPR0@Bn12TYtwCjvWoTbsXfnjWjkZ/yFVZwvUjWVvYyNj1@VGF1AY5T2slba3OBp3HhWGcmn0Ac6BkA222tbbPai29hSCMnoYvd7ZBMbw7/leswwqWMHgp9ntl2IUFCtbfsL/jFBZNe0YD@rFM@@MRpLsdiSh9Pa4K1@pH0ITKnVFcmZKW@MxE7RgrkOSb/l@km/Fnsq@LbFrLRSyH6JIhnc2V4/lmTUdMhc80VhSMeWcuZKEcEHTxVykM/7E@ZLzBRFLOlvw55QTweksFVyIeTgoOPVxP3wB)

Comment: You can remove a lot of spaces and save many more bytes that way

Comment: @corvus_192 I did it! thanks <3

Comment: I'm afraid imports count towards the byte-count, so you'll have to add the cost of `import java.util.*;` for the `HashMap`. As for some golfs in Java 8: `import java.util.*;s->{Map c=new HashMap();for(String a:s.substring(1).split("\\(")){String[]b=a.split("\\)");c.put(b[0],b[1]);}return c;}`. Using Java 11+, you can also use `var` instead: [`s->{var c=new java.util.HashMap();for(var a:s.substring(1).split("\\(")){var b=a.split("\\)");c.put(b[0],b[1]);}return c;}` - **122 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yuzsznsb)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've added `import java.util.*`  towards the byte-count, thanks for let me know!

Comment: You can use the double-brace: `s->{return new HashMap(){{for(String a:s.split("\\(")){String[]b=a.split("\\)");if(b.length>1)put(b[0],b[1]);}}};}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 8 bytes

```
ṣ”(Ḋṣ€”)
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuaPigJ0o4biK4bmj4oKs4oCdKSIsIsOHS+KCrFkiLCIiLFsiXCIoMDEpOTkwMTIzNDU2NzAwMTkoMTApQWIxMjM0XCIiXV0=)

Returns output as a list of key-value pairs.

#### Explanation

```
ṣ”(Ḋṣ€”)    Main Link
ṣ”(         Split at "("
   Ḋ        Drop the first element
    ṣ€”)    Split each line at ")"
```

Answer (score 3):

## K (ngn/k) 14 bytes

```
!/+1_")"\'"("\
```

[Try it here](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxTUNTXNoxX0lSKUVfSUIpR0jAw1LS0NDA0MjYxNTM3MDC01DA00HRMAgkoAQDGAAjR).

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 53 bytes

```swift
let f={($0+"").split{$0=="("}.map{$0.split{$0==")"}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9LCsIwEN3nFGHoIkEpM2ljiZCF51AXCg0Eai1NwEXJ2WsaFdy937zHhJd3sV3XoY/c2UVUuAOQdZgGH5cKrQUBqX7cpkz@VQkppXIV@xADt/zMOAeBJI1BUk2rDx0iGUEoT/dNgH1JNIRKZkcpTZoMakU/p@nG4uQsuzL3nEs59@N3ZMmxafZjFACQ8UVsujwW6D5EZrK15S9YWt8)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split`(`.map(s=>o[([,v]=s.split`)`)[0]]=v,o={})&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1Ba4NAEIXv@RVDDmEWzGZmrQkSVuihlx7SQ48iaExMLcYVV4RS@tvNboKH0Hd8831vvouxsGVfd8O6NafzVOnJ6sRK2zX1kGMur0WHrjEppsGY6fkicpFSlukxMPr3T6xWZtqnC4AlEos4JlbhS7TdEXGMTOL16ItlAJsNEMM6gWcGmHz5wO4zIZMS7qRUxBHHFCl2@hw34wHvPDMPN9y1d9e9hH/xrgNm1/3LFrIy/VtRfqEFnUBpWmuas2zMBd8/Pw7SDn3dXurqByu0wmW6AQ)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

An attempt at a recursive approach.

```javascript
f=(s,[a,b,...c]=s.match(/[^()]+/g))=>a?{[a]:b,...f(s,c)}:{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xbsIwEIZ3nuLEZKvBuXMaUKiSqkOXDu3QMQqScUmaCmIUR5UqxLOn5yAGxD/efd@d/h/za7zt2@Ow6NzXbhzrXPioNNE2UkrZKvfqYAb7LeJyI2T1EDdS5oV5PpWmWk9MzbyV5/XpPD6VM4C5QJJZhqSTx3S5QqRMEMqXbRjMI4hjQIJFAbcMEIbhBZvOJIRa8krrlFLKMNXE@jV8JgDBuWUubrLqJpdfwl2Cy8DV5X/VTNWufzVc1ENegHWdd/ud2rtGvH1@vCs/9G3XtPWf4L6SM/4D)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 58 bytes

```cpp
=WRAPROWS(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([()])0","$1'0"),"()"),2)
```

The formula would be as simple as:

```cpp
=WRAPROWS(SPLIT(A1,"()"),2) // 27 bytes
```

If GS didn't automatically cast the strings to numbers removing leading \$0\$s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```haskell
sL ')'<<tl<sL '('
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxN1czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmm3M0tKSNF2LjcU-Cuqa6jY2JTk2IKaGOkT8pnFuYmaebUFpSXBJkU-eSnFGfrlKmoKShoGhpqWlgaGRsYmpmbmBgaGlhqGBpmMSSEAJonXBAggNAA)

Comment: `map` is exported as `m`, and `(.)` is renamed to `(<)` for technical reasons. This can be: [`sL ')'<<tl<sL '('`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxN1czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmm3M0tKSNF2LjcU-Cuqa6jY2JTk2IKaGOkT8pnFuYmaebUFpSXBJkU-eSnFGfrlKmoKShoGhpqWlgaGRsYmpmbmBgaGlhqGBpmMSSEAJonXBAggNAA)

Comment: On newer versions of hgl you can also do `sa")"<<tl<sa")"`, but `sa` isn't available on ato yet.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 7 bytes

```
<>a@+XW
```

Outputs a list of `[key;value]` pairs. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbLbewSHbQjwiE8qOBNhWglDQNDTUtLA0MjYxNTM3MDA0NLDUMDTcckkABcNwA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
<>a@+XW
     XW ; Regex `\w` (word character: either alphanumeric or underscore)
    +   ; Apply + quantifier (match 1 or more)
  a@    ; Find all matches in command-line argument
<>      ; Group into pairs of elements
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 101 bytes

```java
s->java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split("\\(")).skip(1).map(x->x.split("\\)")).toArray(n->new String[n][])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LbsIwEEXX4StGWY3VxrIJFLW0kbrpriuWwMKFBBkS27IdHqr49nTKQ6kqWfJ4zvW9M1u1V5l1pdmud51unPURttTjbdQ1r1qzitoa/nErpgPXftV6BatahQCfSpvvQXLrhagiXXur19AQwVn02mzmS1B@ExiQMrkbvV7ZI9w182UBFbxBF7KiH@Dde3UKPERfqgapcLWOmC4WmDLGw047lIw3yuExK449Zr842st3NFlhysM9yVAU65JkStP04RAou@LKufqEKQrJ8vFI5kPxJMREiDHKCRuOxXMuUAo2zKWQcpSyX5PKeuhX9fYAL3Db9i8DHcuGEAkYzE6BXty2kTuCES/wAVK4eib/BbXBCzgP6Jy7Hw)

Ungolfed:

```java
s -> java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split("\\("))
    .skip(1)
    .map(x -> x.split("\\)"))
    .toArray(n -> new String[n][])
```

Comment: `n->new String[n][]` can be `String[][]::new` for -3 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda x:dict(re.findall(2*".(\w+)",x))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBDsIgEEDRfU9BXM2oaQYoNjRx4T26aS1EEgoESaynx9a/fD99yysGWe19rH5a52Vi27C4Z4FsWuvCMnkP4nxqYfxc8HTdEBu3ppgLy6bamJl3wTAXWEwmAOHQsL2UXShg4Zjtu2SXABErEEetiQvZqVtPxDVwwsd8QAOSk8AdhVBccU1K8B1lH/4oux8)

Returns a dict. Test harness borrowed from @Mukundan314.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-050lF/\)/ -M5.10.0`, 15 bytes

An alternative solution to [@Xcali's great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272136/9365).

```perl
$,=' -> ';say@F
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJCw9JyAtPiAnO3NheUBGIiwiYXJncyI6Ii0wNTBsRi9cXCkvXG4tTTUuMTAuMCIsImlucHV0IjoiKDAxKTk5MDEyMzQ1NjcwMDE5KDEwKUFiMTIzNCJ9)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 35 bytes

```
{split('(',')').drop(1).chunked(2)}
```

[Try on playground!](https://pl.kotl.in/5xS0W1mLj)

I mean, they are associated, you can find the value for a key:

```
val map = "(01)99012345670019(10)Ab1234(3102)00122515190521(337n)001234".function()

fun getValue(key: String) = map.find { it[0] == key }?.get(1)
println(getValue("10")) // outputs "Ab1234"
```